# What's going wrong with this prime-number output?

Tags: python

```
from math import sqrt

for num in range(2,100) :
    flag = True
    for sub in range(2,int(sqrt(num))+1) :
        if num % sub ==0 :
            flag = False
            break
        print num ,
```

[image: This is the output, repeated numbers]

I am a "brand" newbie in python, I try code to output the prime number from 2 to 100, and I 
encountered some question, please help me  ^^

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: Images are useful to illustrate something that isn't text. Since your code and output is all text, please put text in the question.

Comment: Rename `flag` to `isprime`, and then **use** it somewhere ;-)  What you want is probably `if isprime: print num,` indented at the same level as your `for sub ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 for sub in range(2,int(sqrt(num))+1) :
    if num % sub ==0 :
        flag = False
        break
    print num , # <<-- this is inside the for loop and will be printed every iteration
```

Comment: 1 from math import sqrt
    2 
    3 for num in range(2,100)  :
    4     isprime = True
    5     for sub in range(2,int(sqrt(num))+1) :
    6         if num % sub ==0 :
    7             isprime = False
    8             break
    9     if isprime :
   10         print num ,